# finding the limit of $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\tan(x)}{x-\sin(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm calculating the limit for the following equation, and would like some feedback on my solution. The answer is $-2$ although, I cannot seem to derive this whilst using l'hopitals rule.

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\tan(x)}{x-\sin(x)}$

my working out:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x-\tan(x))}{\frac{d}{dx}(x-\sin(x))}=\frac{1-\sec^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)} = \frac{\tan^2(x)(1+\cos(x))}{1-\cos^2(x)}=0$$

Comment: What makes you think that the limit is zero? The last expression is still of the form $0/0$ for $x \to 0$.

Comment: How did you get $=0$, and where did the minus sign from $1-\sec^2 x=-\tan^2 x$ go?

Comment: It seems OK (except for wrting $=$ for things that are not equal) up to $\frac{\tan^2(x)(1+\cos(x))}{1-\cos^2(x)}$, but that still has indeterminate form $0/0$.

Comment: Hint: you divided by zero. Just keep applying lhopital

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1516339/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/508733/42969.

Comment: Aha! I understand it properly now. I was afraid of trying to apply l'hospitals constantly, although the comments make it far clearer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The Maclaurin series for tan(x) is:

\begin{equation*}
\tan x=x+\frac{x^{3}}{3} +\frac{2x^{5}}{15} +...
\end{equation*}
And that for sin(x) is
\begin{gather*}
\sin x=x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!} +\frac{x^{5}}{5!} +...\\
\end{gather*}
Can you use this data to get to the answer?